# Meteor Simple schema validator in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mongoose

I have a background process which updates some data in Meteor, and is quite DB intensive.

I've come to the conclusion that for data which doesn't need to be reactive, I'm better off bypassing Meteor and updating the data directly, as the synchronous nature of it's DB access appears to be creating load within the Meteor process which i'd rather not have.

To do this, I am using Mongoose, which appears to work very well, in that there is next to no load when using Mongoose, but when using Meteor CPU is very high.  The validators are a little different however if I avoid RegEx validators I am fine.

The issue I am having with this approach is exporting the Meteor simple schema validators for use in Mongoose.  I have created the schema object in /lib/schema.js, which works fine for Meteor. When I try to export the object using module.exports for using in Mongoose, I get a 
*module is not defined* error.

If I attempt to import module using:

```
var module = Meteor.require('module');
schemaObject = {
  prop1: {
    type: String,
    label: "Property 1",
     max: 24
  },
  prop2: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Another property",
    max: 9999
  },
}
module.exports.schemaObject = schemaObject;
```

I get a *Cannot set property 'schemaObject' of undefined* error. 
Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing Meteor code as Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing last line with:

```
  module.export = {
    schemaObject: schemaObject
  }
```

Comment: Great, this gets me past the errors I was seeing previously. I now encounter a _Meteor is not defined_ ReferenceError in the Mongoose Code due to the Meteor.require.